# Running node script when starting .NET test suite

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, testing, mspec

I'm looking for a way to connect a test neo4j db to my Mspec test suite. If found [neodb](https://github.com/catalint/neodb). Is there a way that I can create a script that runs everytime the test suite is run?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Context before_all
```

To execute code before your tests

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class deriving from `IAssemblyContext` mspec will run it before any of the mspec contexts in the respective assembly. This is useful for general global setup.

Specific setup for mspec contexts (classes with `It` delegates) goes into `Establish` delegates.